# static and dynamic resolution in C++

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

The text I'm following says:

> A call to a virtual function using an object is always resolved statically. You *only* get a dynamic resolution through a pointer or a reference.

Now consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

class Mainclass{
    protected: 
        double length{1.0};
        double width{1.0};
        double height{1.0};

    public:
        Mainclass(double lv, double wv, double hv):length{lv}, width{wv}, height{hv}{
            std::cout<<"Three args box ran"<<std::endl;
        }

        void showVolume() const{
            std::cout<<"Mainclass usable volume is: "<<Volume()<<std::endl;
        }

        virtual double Volume() const{
            return length*width*height;
        }

};


class Derivedclass: public Mainclass{
    public: 
        Derivedclass(double lv, double wv, double hv): Mainclass{lv, wv, hv}{}

        double Volume() const{
            return 0.85*length*width*height;
        }

};

int main(){
    Mainclass first{20.0, 30.0, 40.0};
    Derivedclass second {20.0, 30.0, 40.0};

    first.showVolume();
    second.showVolume();
}
```

Output:

```
Three args box ran
Three args box ran
Mainclass usable volume is: 24000
Mainclass usable volume is: 20400
```

Here, I'm calling the base class and the derived class objects via their object instances and *not* through a pointer. But it appears that the function is being resolved dynamically. Was the text wrong? If not what did it mean?

Comment: Where are you getting that the function is resolved dynamically in your example? Do you know what dynamic resolution (dynamic binding) is?

Comment: @M.M How is it dynamic when `this` is a pointer to the static type?

Comment: @0x499602D2 , if it weren't it would have to output the same volume right?

Comment: @0x499602D2 the type of `this` in `showVolume` is  `Mainclass *`, but the derived class `Volume()` function is called

Comment: @M.M Oops. Did not see that call to `Volume` inside `showVolume()`.

Comment: The actual rule is that virtual function dispatch always uses the *dynamic type* of the object (not the static type of the expression on which the function was called) . The gist of the quote is that if you call a virtual function on the name of an object , then in that situation the dynamic type of the object is always the same as the type of that name so the compiler can optimize the process and not need to emit a vtable lookup

Comment: @M.M , you mean it _is_ dynamic resolution when you say: "is "dynamic resolution through a pointer" because it means this->Volume()"

Comment: @niceboy-programmer I would say that all virtual function dispatch is "dynamic resolution"; as has been mentioned already, in some situations the compiler can optimize the process but I think it is misleading to describe those situations as "static resolution"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "A call to a virtual function using an object is always resolved statically. You only get a dynamic resolution through a pointer or a reference."

This sentence isn't so much describing a rule of the C++ language as a shortcut compilers are allowed to take.

You are calling `showFunction` directly on the names of objects.  So suppose `showFunction` were declared virtual.  The compiler knows the exact types of the objects called `first` and `second`: there's no way they could actually be objects of some other type.  So although the language says any overriding function must be called by `first.showVolume()` and `second.showVolume()`, there's no possible way the result will be any functions other than the ones the compiler can find immediately, so it doesn't actually need to put any code for determining which function to call in the resulting program.  The correct function `Mainclass::showVolume()` (or `Derivedclass::showVolume()`, if it existed), can be called directly, which can be slightly more efficient.

The quote doesn't apply to the call of `Volume()` inside `showVolume()`.  Since `Volume` names a non-static member, `Volume()` means the same as `this->Volume()`.  `this` is a pointer, which might or might not point at an object whose complete type matches the type `Mainclass* const` of the pointer.  So in this case, the compiler is required to do dynamic resolution to determine which function to call.

But one more thing to note: it's true you can only get dynamic resolution through a pointer or reference, but it's not true you *always* get dynamic resolution through a pointer or reference.  When a function is named as a "qualified id" using the `::` token, the language says the function called is determined statically, and overrides are ignored.  For example, if your code in `showVolume()` changed to use either `Mainclass::Volume()` or `this->Mainclass::Volume()`, you would see that it never calls `Derivedclass::Volume`.

Comment: I'm confused by: "You are calling showFunction directly on the names of objects. So suppose showFunction were declared virtual. The compiler knows the exact types of the objects called first and second: there's no way they could actually be objects of some other type." part, because if showVolume were declared virtual, then the output shows that the resolution is static, i.e. they both output 24000

Comment: @niceboy-programmer there are *two* function calls in your example, one to `showVolume` and one to `Volume`. The one to `showVolume` will not need to be dynamic, even if it was declared virtual and implemented differently in both classes. The one to `Volume` is resolved dynamically.